# Could not set shared folder

Tags: 14.04, networking, xubuntu, samba

I'm running on Xubuntu 14.04.2 LTS. Trying to share a folder on a network via shares-admin and system-config-samba applications but they give me error.

command

> sudo shares-admin

output:

```
error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment.
error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment.

(shares-admin:11220): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:
```

command

> sudo system-config-samba

output:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py:57: GtkWarning: could not open display
  warnings.warn(str(e), _gtk.Warning)
/usr/share/system-config-samba/mainWindow.py:62: Warning: invalid (NULL) pointer instance
  self.xml = gtk.glade.XML ("/usr/share/system-config-samba/system-config-samba.glade", domain="system-config-samba")
/usr/share/system-config-samba/mainWindow.py:62: Warning: g_signal_connect_data: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed
  self.xml = gtk.glade.XML ("/usr/share/system-config-samba/system-config-samba.glade", domain="system-config-samba")
/usr/share/system-config-samba/mainWindow.py:62: GtkWarning: IA__gtk_settings_get_for_screen: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed
  self.xml = gtk.glade.XML ("/usr/share/system-config-samba/system-config-samba.glade", domain="system-config-samba")
/usr/share/system-config-samba/mainWindow.py:62: Warning: g_object_get: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
  self.xml = gtk.glade.XML ("/usr/share/system-config-samba/system-config-samba.glade", domain="system-config-samba")
/usr/share/system-config-samba/mainWindow.py:62: GtkWarning: IA__gdk_pango_context_get_for_screen: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed
  self.xml = gtk.glade.XML ("/usr/share/system-config-samba/system-config-samba.glade", domain="system-config-samba")
/usr/share/system-config-samba/mainWindow.py:62: PangoWarning: pango_context_set_font_description: assertion 'context != NULL' failed
  self.xml = gtk.glade.XML ("/usr/share/system-config-samba/system-config-samba.glade", domain="system-config-samba")
/usr/share/system-config-samba/mainWindow.py:62: PangoWarning: pango_context_set_base_dir: assertion 'context != NULL' failed
  self.xml = gtk.glade.XML ("/usr/share/system-config-samba/system-config-samba.glade", domain="system-config-samba")
/usr/share/system-config-samba/mainWindow.py:62: PangoWarning: pango_context_set_language: assertion 'context != NULL' failed
  self.xml = gtk.glade.XML ("/usr/share/system-config-samba/system-config-samba.glade", domain="system-config-samba")
/usr/share/system-config-samba/mainWindow.py:62: PangoWarning: pango_layout_new: assertion 'context != NULL' failed
  self.xml = gtk.glade.XML ("/usr/share/system-config-samba/system-config-samba.glade", domain="system-config-samba")
/usr/share/system-config-samba/mainWindow.py:62: PangoWarning: pango_layout_set_attributes: assertion 'layout != NULL' failed
  self.xml = gtk.glade.XML ("/usr/share/system-config-samba/system-config-samba.glade", domain="system-config-samba")
/usr/share/system-config-samba/mainWindow.py:62: PangoWarning: pango_layout_set_text: assertion 'layout != NULL' failed
  self.xml = gtk.glade.XML ("/usr/share/system-config-samba/system-config-samba.glade", domain="system-config-samba")
/usr/share/system-config-samba/mainWindow.py:62: PangoWarning: pango_layout_get_unknown_glyphs_count: assertion 'PANGO_IS_LAYOUT (layout)' failed
  self.xml = gtk.glade.XML ("/usr/share/system-config-samba/system-config-samba.glade", domain="system-config-samba")
/usr/share/system-config-samba/mainWindow.py:62: Warning: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
  self.xml = gtk.glade.XML ("/usr/share/system-config-samba/system-config-samba.glade", domain="system-config-samba")
/usr/share/system-config-samba/mainWindow.py:62: Warning: value "TRUE" of type 'gboolean' is invalid or out of range for property 'visible' of type 'gboolean'
  self.xml = gtk.glade.XML ("/usr/share/system-config-samba/system-config-samba.glade", domain="system-config-samba")
/usr/share/system-config-samba/mainWindow.py:62: GtkWarning: IA__gdk_screen_get_display: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed
  self.xml = gtk.glade.XML ("/usr/share/system-config-samba/system-config-samba.glade", domain="system-config-samba")
/usr/share/system-config-samba/mainWindow.py:62: GtkWarning: IA__gdk_keymap_get_for_display: assertion 'GDK_IS_DISPLAY (display)' failed
  self.xml = gtk.glade.XML ("/usr/share/system-config-samba/system-config-samba.glade", domain="system-config-samba")
```

any idea about what's going wrong?

Comment: Can you check if you have enabled access to your X server via `xhost +` in the terminal window?

Comment: @lemonslice this is terminal output: "access control disabled, clients can connect from any host", what do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some googling I ended up with this solution:

```
pkexec env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY shares-admin
```

It passes required environment variables to the new isolated environment. Since root doesn't have DISPLAY and XAUTHORITY variables in its environment, user must pass it before the root uses any application dependent on GUI.

(Now I started to think how can I make them permanent when sudo called...)

Comment: You can check if `gksu -k` passes this sort of arguments. That is `gksu -k shares-admin`

Comment: I found that mistakenly I set wrong parameters in sudoers files. That was the cause..

Answer (score 0):

another solutions is to

```
sudo apt-get install gksu
gksu-properties
```

Set authentication mode to sudo and grab mode to enable